# Is it okay to use my own app from my own device which contains AdMob advertisements

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store, admob

I have implemented an iOS application which has AdMob advertisements in it.

As far as I know if you don't identify your device as a test device during the development phase, Google finds it out and suspends (temporarily or even permanently sometimes) your account.

My app is live on AppStore now. Can I use my own app? Since I used my iPhone as a test device before, I am a little bit worried about it.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Don't worry. As long as you don't click the ads and don't use it too much while developing (+1000 views), there's nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the app is in production phase and live in the app store, you can use it as any normal user would. However, you should refrain from clicking the ads multiple times as that would lead to click fraud.